# Should i use foreign key or not

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose i want to create a database to store login and personal detail of a user then should i **create one table**

```
Only One table Table User
Username(varchar255)|User_id(int)|Name(varchar255)|Sex(0,1,2)|DOB(Date)|Password(char64)|
```

OR **two table with a foreign key**

```
Table User_Login

    User_id(int)|Username(varchar255)|Password(char64)|

and table User_Detail

    User_id(int)|Name(varchar255)|Sex(0,1,2)|DOB(Date)|
```

Comment: What do _you_ think, and why?

Comment: I am not db expert so I post my opinion in the comment : If you have a 1-1 relation, i think it is pointless to do a foreign key as you will need to do some useless joins.

Comment: if you want to support historical records of users sexes as they transition, and enter the witness protection program and get multiple birth-dates, then by all means use the 2-table structure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the first one because it will reduce db size but not sure whether my login query would still be fast or not

Comment: @Ankit: Try it and see.

Comment: query speeds have almost NO dependence on how many fields are in a table, unless you're a lazy programmer and only ever do `select *`. but `select onefield from ...` will be the same speed whether there's 500 fields or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself these questions.

Will a user have one or more than one user name?

Will a user have one or more than one password?  This includes previous passwords if you want to check for unique passwords over a period of time.

Will a user have one or more than one name?

Will a user have one or more than one gender?

Will a user have one or more than one date of birth?

When the answer to a question is "one", then that column belongs in the user table.

When the answer to a question is "more than one" then that column belongs in a different table.

This process is called the first normal form of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Based on your answer, there's never a reason for 1-1 tables, which actually is required if you want to avoid NULL columns (necessary for the "higher" normal forms)

Comment: @landons: You're describing 4th normal form.  Let's get past 1st, 2nd, and 3rd first.  :-)

Comment: Fair enough ;).  Was a little surprised by a comment above that said that 1-1's are pointless.

Comment: @landons: The OP's 1-1 may be pointless.  There's no way to know without going through the 1st normal form questions.  As an example, I would put user name and password in separate tables because I'd want to allow for user name changes and to check passwords for uniqueness.  Then my user table would have a 1 - N relationship with my user name table and my password table.

Answer (score 0):

I think theres two popular ways of how to define a table, 3NF and BNCF (They will be well documented).

The rules are:

- There should be no dulicate columns (easy one)
- Remove columns that are not fully dependent upon the primary key (look at the attributes and if they make sense when standing alone then they should be in a seperate table (Something like that)

Its quite hard to grasp first time so have a read of 1NF, 2NF, 3NF and BNCF